# List specific objects in AWS S3 SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to delete multiple objects in a bucket using SDK, but when i pass the list of KeyVersions to the method .deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest), he actually deletes the objects from my list, but if i pass a list that contain one or more objects that aren't inside the Bucket it deletes the objects found and does not return which objects weren't deleted because wasn't found.

```
private void deleteMultipleObjectsFromS3(final List<KeyVersion> objectsKeys) {
    final DeleteObjectsRequest deleteObjectsRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest(this.bucketName)
            .withKeys(objectsKeys)
            .withQuiet(false);

    try {
          s3Client.deleteObjects(deleteObjectsRequest);
        } catch (final AmazonServiceException e) {
          throw new AmazonSdkException(e, e.getErrorMessage(), DELETE_OPERATION, 
          this.bucketName, objectsKeys.toString());
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
          throw new AmazonSdkException(e, e.getLocalizedMessage(), DELETE_OPERATION, this.bucketName, objectsKeys.toString());
    }
  }
```

The response get all objects that i passed, i need to inform in the endpoint which objects were, or not, deleted.

[image]

I'm using Java SDK version 1.12.181

EDIT 1:

I've also tried to get the objects sumaries, but it returns all objects in the bucket. What i don't want, because some buckets that i'll operate might have more than 100.000 objects.

```
final ListObjectsV2Result listObjectsV2Result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest);
final List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjectSummary = listObjectsV2Result.getObjectSummaries();
```

Comment: The V1 API you are using is old and not best practice. Look at using V2.... https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3

Comment: From the base S3 API: "[If there isn't a null version, Amazon S3 does not remove any objects but will still respond that the command was successful](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html)."  In other words, S3 itself has no way to atomically determine if an object exists and if it does, delete it.  At best, you can see if it exists before you attempt to delete it, but it's possible it will be created after you check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeleteItem` will still return a successful response if the object does not exist. This is irrespective of SDK version or language as this response is returned by the underlying S3 API.

If you need to know an object has been deleted or not, since you're on the v1 of the Java SDK:

1. For every object, call [`doesObjectExist`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#doesObjectExist-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) passing in the bucket name & object name
2. If `true` is returned, add to a `toBeDeleted` list
3. If `false` is returned, add to a `notDeleted` list
4. Call `deleteObjects` for the items in `toBeDeleted`
5. If any items failed to be deleted, remove from `toBeDeleted` & add to `notDeleted`

Anything in `notDeleted`, was not deleted & anything in `toBeDeleted` was deleted.

Comment: Yeah, i've implemented this way but noticed that some clients will delete a massive number of objects, if for each object i need to call this method that will not be good, because will increase the response time and will be way more expensive. In v2 is possible to do this? If there it is i'll consider upgrading it.

Comment: No, this is an API response & is the same across all SDks